# TypeError: First element of field tuple is neither a tuple nor str

Tags: rapids, cudf

I am a beginner to RAPIDS. I am trying to run the following code on Colab. It is resulting in an error.
TypeError: First element of field tuple is neither a tuple nor str

Similari code runs well while using pandas. But failing while using cudf dataframe apply.

Code Snippet:

dataSet_formatted_gdf = cudf.DataFrame.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(dataset_formatted_npa))
conAttrs_gdf = cudf.DataFrame.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(dataset_formatted_npa[:, 0]))

equivalenceClasses = conAttrs_gdf.groupby(0).groups

decAttr_gdf = cudf.DataFrame.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(dataset_formatted_npa[:, 1]))

decisionClasses = decAttr_gdf.groupby(0).groups

rough_membership_values = dataSet_formatted_gdf.apply(lambda x: calculateRoughMembership(x, equivalenceClasses, decisionClasses), axis=1)

Comment: You may want to check out Stackoverflow's [guidelines on Minimal, Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is likely not enough information here to help you effectively.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.